# Rally .NET: Query for project admins that belong to a specific project?

Tags: c#, web-services, rally

I am looking for a List object that is populated with project admins for a specific project that is within a specific workspace.
Would like some sample code that can query the API for to retrieve all the project admins *email addresses*. 
Here is some sample code I have tried.

```
    public void getProjectAdmins(string workspaceRef, string projectRef)
    {
        this.EnsureRallyIsAuthenticated();

        Request projectAdminRequest = new Request("User");
        projectAdminRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
        projectAdminRequest.Project = projectRef;
        projectAdminRequest.ProjectScopeUp = RallyConstant.ProjectScopeUp;
        projectAdminRequest.ProjectScopeDown = RallyConstant.ProjectScopeDown;

        projectAdminRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
        {
            "Admin", "Email"
        };

        try
        {
            //query the items in the list
            projectAdminRequest.Query = new Query();
            QueryResult result = _rallyRestApi.Query(projectAdminRequest);

            //iterate through the result set
            foreach (var admin in result.Results)
            {
                var adminResult = admin[RallyConstant.Owner];
                if (adminResult != null)
                {
                    var x = adminResult[RallyQueryConstant.ReferenceObject];

                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(RallyQueryConstant.WebExceptionMessage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any code written yet?  Stackoverflow generally works the best if you have some code to share first...

Comment: @KyleMorse

I have just updated the question to include some code I tried.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to query the ProjectPermission endpoint filtered to your project in question like so:

```
Request projectAdminRequest = new Request("ProjectPermission");
projectAdminRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
projectAdminRequest.Fetch = new List<string>() {"User", "EmailAddress"};
projectAdminRequest.Query = Query.And(
    new Query("Project", Query.Operator.Equals, "/project/12345"),
    new Query("Role", Query.Operator.Equals, "Project Admin"));
```

Fetching User and EmailAddress should include the data you're looking for in your request.

Comment: I have added the snippet below, and I do not get any results
I also get a 0 returned when I call the Count() on the result set, but my project reference is valid and has 2 project admins.

   `QueryResult pAdminResult = _rallyRestApi.Query(projectAdminRequest);

            foreach (var admin in pAdminResult.Results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(admin["User"]);
            }`

Comment: Oh, right- I bet there are errors.  If you try again later today I bet it will start working- the Project attribute on ProjectPermission wasn't previously filterable, but I fixed that for this afternoon's deployment...  Sorry I forgot to mention that in the answer!

Comment: `QueryResult pAdminResult = _rallyRestApi.Query(projectAdminRequest);
            Console.WriteLine(pAdminResult.Results.Any()); //returns false
` Just wondering if my code is correct, I added these two lines to the end of your answer snippet. I can wait till its deployed.